# The difference between Python's subprocess.Popen with shell=True and a real shell

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

When I open a command line I want it to start in the same working directory where the currently active window is.
Therefore I have written a python script which figures out the correct path. It takes as argument a command which opens a terminal. In this argument it replaces a placeholder with the desired directory and executes the command with

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

The string `cmd` is correctly assembled to:

```
xterm -e 'cd '\''/mnt/data/software/computer/tools/i3'\''; /usr/bin/bash'
```

If I execute this command in bash it opens xterm in the correct directory as desired.
If I execute this command from the python script xterm does *not* open.

Where is the difference?

---

Additional information:

I am using Python 3.6.5.

`echo $SHELL` returns `/bin/bash`.

The keybinding to the script in my i3 config:

```
bindsym $mod+Return exec "/mnt/data/software/computer/tools/i3/i3_launch_cwd.sh \\"xterm -e 'cd %{cwd}; /usr/bin/bash'\\""
```

(This shell script is just a simple wrapper which redirects stderr to a log file for debugging)

After executing the following command in bash xterm does open even from python:

```
xrdb -merge -I$HOME ~/.Xresources
```

The relevant line in Xresources is

```
xterm*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono Book
```

Why does that make a difference?

---

**Solution**:
Thanks to Charles Duffy's comments I have found the problem.
In my python script I am redirecting stderr with `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` but I forgot to read stderr.
Before loading my Xresources file which sets the font xterm prints a warning to stderr that a font can not be loaded.
xterm has a very small buffer. Because my program is not reading stderr the buffer is not cleared and xterm is blocked.

Replacing

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

with

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
sys.stderr.write(err)
```

Would solve the problem.
But because I am not doing anything with stderr there is no need to redirect it in the first place.
So instead I am now using

```
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Comment: `shell=True` **is** a real shell. It literally passes your list after the prefix `['sh', '-c']`.

Comment: BTW, redirecting stderr changes the way bash behaves in some respects that might be more substantial than you intend. stderr is where the prompt is printed, for example.

Comment: ...btw, note that `shell=True` *always* uses `/bin/sh`; what your `$SHELL` is is completely irrelevant.

Comment: When you say "correctly assembled" -- that string **isn't** correct; it needs to have another closing quote after the `bash`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true, I missed the trailing quote when copying the command. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `shell=True`; it's not appropriate to your use case.

```
import subprocess
try:
    from pipes import quote # Python 2
except ImportError:
    from shlex import quote # Python 3

dir='/mnt/data/software/computer/tools/i3'
p = subprocess.Popen(['xterm', '-e', 'cd %s && exec bash' % quote(dir)])
```

However, you can simplify this by letting `subprocess.Popen` set the directory for you:

```
dir='/mnt/data/software/computer/tools/i3'
p = subprocess.Popen(['xterm', '-e', 'bash'], cwd=dir)
```

That said, `shell=True` *is* 100% equivalent to running `sh -c '...command...'`, where your command's literal text is in `...command...`; this is *exactly what it does in practice*.

---

Note that I removed `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` above. You *can* add that back in, but only if you have your code *actually read* content written to stderr, as by calling `communicate()`.

Comment: unfortunately, "`shell=True` is 100% equivalent to running `sh -c '...command...'`" does not seems to be the case on my system. I have tried adding `bindsym $mod+x exec "sh -c \\"xterm -e 'cd '\''/mnt/data'\''; /usr/bin/bash'\\""` to my i3 config and that does open xterm. I have also tried running the python script directly without redirecting it's output. I see no other difference except that one command is executed via python and one directly.

Comment: It is interesting that the `SHELL` variable does not influence the execution through python. I thought I had read it did but maybe I don't remember that correctly.

Comment: I know that it is usually preferred to use `shell=False` but in this case I am reading the command that the user wants to be executed from an argument that is passed to my python script. I don't see why I should split that up into a list. That is why I am using `shell=True` here.

Comment: I forgot trying to remove `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` from the python script. I have just tried that and that is really it! I have no clue why this should have a difference on whether xterm opens or not but it does. If you add that to your answer I will accept it.

Comment: Quick question -- is anything actually *reading* from that pipe?  If the process is trying to write to stderr but nothing is reading, the write would block, and that would explain your behavior -- `xterm` wouldn't be able to get past the first part of its code that tries to write (more than the very short buffer length) to the pipe.

Comment: that's it! I really forgot to call `communicate()`. But since I would just print what's written on the subprocess' stderr to sys.stderr I guess I better don't redirect stderr in the first place. Thanks a lot for your help! Now it makes sense. Now I see an error message from xterm *cannot load font*. And after loading my Xressources file the font is set correctly, it does not write to stderr anymore and so it does not block.